# Error reading an animated GIF file in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gif, animated-gif

I read GIF files in the following way:

```
[image, map] = imread(imagePath, 'frames', 1);
```

However, reading the GIF image posted below I get the following error message:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in readgif>read_multiframe_gif (line 117)
    [X(:,:,:,j) undisposed_index] =
    handle_positive_base_frame(data{j},info(j),X(:,:,:,undisposed_index),X(:,:,:,j-1),undisposed_index,j);

Error in readgif (line 36)
[X,map] = read_multiframe_gif(filename);

Error in imread (line 435)
    [X, map] = feval(fmt_s.read, filename, extraArgs{:});
```

Is it because the GIF file is corrupted or is there another problem?

[image]

Comment: I get exactly the same error with that file (Matlab R2012b, OS X 10.8.3). Other animated gifs (e.g. [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rotating_earth_(large).gif)) open fine. Opening the file in a hex viewer it looks like something may be wrong with it -probably in the header. Some programs may be tolerant to malformed headers, but I guess Matlab isn't. How was the image created? Can you open in another program and resave it?

Comment: @MarvinTheParanoidAndroid: I think you're completely misinterpreting the help for `imread`. `idx` is a user-specified variable, either a scalar or vector range of frames.

Comment: I haven't created it. Resaving it could be a solution; however, I was wondering if there was something wrong with the way I processed it or with the file itself.

Comment: @JohnManak have you tried increasing the 1 to say 10 for example?

Comment: What happens when you re-convert it to GIF using IrfanView? That operation should re-create the frames and re-package the GIF, so if the file is damaged, the header is corrupt, or something to that effect, this will correct it. MATLAB doesn't make much of an attempt to recover imperfect data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As horchler says in the comments, it seems that Matlab isn't tolerant to malformed image files and doesn't read them even though other image programs may open them.

Answer (score 0):

A utility for playing Gif files like this one may help

[GIF Player](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12673)